# Is it possible to implement sticky move tolerance in a ArcGIS JavaScript API application?

Tags: arcgis-server, javascript, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

We are working on a project in ArcGIS JavaScript and is going fine. We want to add [sticky move tolerance](http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/GISDictionary/term/sticky%20move%20tolerance) to our project so it will not be so easy to move features on the map.

Is it not possible to add that to our project? Does anyone know anything about that?

Answer (score 2):

In v. 3.5 of the ArcGIS JavaScript API [Edit toolbar](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/edit.html), there is an [onGraphicMoveStop](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/edit.html#ongraphicmovestop) event that fires when you stop moving the graphic. The event gives you the graphic and a transform object, which includes a dx (delta-x) and dy (delta-y). I think these are in screen units, but I'm not sure. Anyway, you can calculate the distance the distance dragged from those, and test it against your application's sticky move tolerance value.

While I haven't worked out how to stop the point from being dragged out until you exceed sticky tolerance, I have an [example on jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/raykendo/pfeNF/1/) that stops the graphic from being written back to the FeatureLayer if the sticky tolerance isn't exceeded. The example checks [onVertexMoveStop](https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/edit.html#onvertexmovestop) for vertex editing